# How to make right arrow/enter keypress or click on next button not increase score?

Tags: angular

In my quiz app I would like it so that if the right arrow key or enter key on keyboard is pressed or next button is clicked (in dependency-injection-quiz.component.html), the score should not be increased by 1 if no answer is provided. If a user zips through the quiz as mentioned, I would like in the User Answers field for "(no answer provided)" to be displayed for each question skipped in the mat-accordion Results. Please see my Stackblitz at: **https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-quiz-app**

```
<div class="next-question-nav" *ngIf="question && questionIndex !== totalQuestions">
  <button type="button" mat-flat-button (click)="nextQuestion()"
    (window:keydown.ArrowRight)="nextQuestion()"
    (window:keydown.Enter)="nextQuestion()"
    matTooltip="Next Question &raquo;" matTooltipPosition="above">
    SVG next code
  </button>
</div>
```

in checkIfAnsweredCorrectly() (nextQuestion() calls this function):

```
if (!incorrectAnswerFound) {
  this.sendCorrectCountToQuizService(this.correctCount + 1);
}
```

Comment: `incorrectAnswerFound` is returning false when you press enter or right arrow. So, !false is true and is calling `sendCorrectCountToQuizService`. Fix this method here `checkIfAnsweredCorrectly`.

Comment: I've removed the keypresses from HTML and now I need to fix the problem of increasing when the user clicks the next button in the form. Also would like in multiple choice question (question 1) for all answers to be marked as correct for the score to increase.

Answer (score 1):

if you want people to be able to skip questions without it scoring, then don't include any correct/incorrect logic until the form is completed.

Or maybe add a "Add up Scores" button that handles all scoring?

or keep track of 3 variables:

```
var questionsSkipped = 0;
var questionsAnsweredCorrectly = 0;
var questionsAnsweredIncorrectly = 0;
```

there are lots of ways to solve this. depend on what you want.